# ApplicationController Method with Equal Sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 4 I'm trying to do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 # does not work
  def x=(value)
    session[:x] = value
  end

  # I have to do this instead
  def set_x(value)
    session[:x] = value
  end 

end
```

When I try to call `x = 1` from a child controller, I don't get an error, however the session variable doesn't get set. Running `set_x 1` works as expected though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a problem of scope, instead of calling `x = 1`, try to call `self.x = 1`.

Comment: By writing `x=1`, you actually create a new variable instead of calling the method of the parent controller.